# Can more than one boost::signal be connected to 1 slot?

Tags: c++, boost, signals

i know i can connect multiple slots to the same signal.

but Can I do it the other way round? having 3 signals connected to the same slot?

anyone ever tried this?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from connecting more than one signal to a slot.

Do it if you need to, it'll work fine.